# Bash script email doesn't ignore the html part in output

Tags: shell-script, email, html

LE. I killed everything html related. Declared 2 variables R and G (for red and green).

My mail shows the status **[0;32mGLOBAL_STATUS = OK**, obvious not in colours.

If I comment my variables I receive in the email GLOBAL_STATUS = OK -> no colours.

*Pretty please help me receive the mail with green GLOBAL_STATUS = OK*

---

I wrote this part of the code, but it doesn’t print in the email I should receive: GLOBAL_STATUS = OK in green ☹

It shows on top of the email: `<h1> <span style='color:green;'>  GLOBAL_STATUS = OK </span></h1><br/><br/><br/>`

And at the end of the email: `<html>` `<body>` `<br><br><br> </body> </html>`

**What am I doing wrong?** I tried to eliminate the html, body, etc parts, but still, the beginning of the mail is the same: `<h1> <span style='color:green;'>  GLOBAL_STATUS = OK </span></h1><br/><br/><br/>`

```
#echo "<html> ">>$LOG
#echo "<body>" >> $LOG
#echo "<br><br><br>" >> $LOG
#echo "<br><br><br>" >> $LOG
R='\033[0;31m'
G='\033[0;32m'
content="tmp.txt"
global_status=0
while read line; do
   if [[ "$line" == *"KO"* && "$global_status" == "0" ]]; then
         echo -e "\n\n\n $line";
         ((global_status=!global_status));
         echo -e "\n $global_status"
   fi
   echo "$line" >> $content
done < $LOG

#echo "<h1>" > $LOG
if [ "$global_status" -eq 0 ]; then
     echo -e "${G}GLOBAL_STATUS = OK" > $LOG
else 
     echo -e "${R}GLOBAL_STATUS = KO" > $LOG
fi
cat $content >> $LOG
rm tmp.txt
#echo "</body>" >> $LOG
#echo "</html>" >> $LOG
mail -s "Check Back" lola@domain.com < /home/check_back.log
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Pleas edit your post to specify how the generated e-mail is being sent to you. How do you ensure that the e-mail is sent in HTML format and not in plain-text format (which would treat all HTML commands as literal text, not formatting instructions)?

Comment: I edited the email part. The problem is that I need to check 17 servers status. And print if one KO, Global status KO. If all OK, Global Status ok. The servers status and info is super ok, just this snippet of code for GLOBAL STATUS is not working.

Comment: In seems you have a typo. The line `echo "<h1>" > $LOG` should read `echo "<h1>" >> $LOG`, otherwise you are overwriting everything written to the file so far.

Comment: if I put >> it doesn't send any status, only my servers information

Comment: you use `$LOG` both as mail body and status control (in while loop) ?

Comment: The line `echo "<h1>" > $LOG` delete `$LOG`, the line `cat $content >> $LOG` put back *after* the beginnig of `$LOG`. I would suggest using two different files: one for mail body, another for control.

Comment: I think, yes. Sorry, but I'm so new at this. I need to continue this script, but I don't have an IT background. I'm an electrical engineer. With google and some other scripts done by some colleagues I arrived here with the script. I clean it, improve it, but now, the OK or KO status kills me

Comment: I have a bit of a hard time following this script. Partly because you're writing all that stuff to a file named in `$LOG`, but you never seem to read from it after. Unless `LOG` is assigned to `/home/check_back.log`, but that's not shown. If it isn't, and you're actually reading and writing to/from two different files, well that's probably your problem. Otherwise, that's a part of the script you might want to clear up. Also with `tmp.txt`, it might be better to start by clearing the file (with e.g. `printf > "$content"`); now it looks the first write is an append, so any old data would be kept

Comment: Also, do I get it right that you want to _remove_ the HTML tags from the email, and add that terminal escape for the colors instead? That looks odd, or at least I would have expected that few email clients would support terminal escapes. But a few do support HTML.

Comment: @ilkkachu I lost a lot of days with the html part, as my colleagues think it should be done like that, but they don't know how. So I try something else. I cleaned all the html, and the email is super ok. Everything looks ok, when I have a KO process I have the GLOBAL_STATUS=KO, or Status OK, if all ok. Still my ''homework'' is to show this status in colours. I have no more ideas, and I'm panicking as the dead line is the end of the month. My $LOG is declared and called at the beginning of my script with the servers part.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on this:

> Pretty please help me receive the mail with green GLOBAL_STATUS = OK

One problem you might have could be the `Content-type` header. If it marks the message as plaintext (`text/plain`), it'll likely show as such. You'll need to change the header to mark the type as `text/html`.

E.g. with the `mail` command from Debian's `bsd-mailx` package, this works at least as received by Gmail.

```
#!/bin/sh

emailaddr=whatever@example.org
mail -s "colortest" -a 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"' "$emailaddr" << EOF
<html>

<h1> <span style='color:green;'>  GLOBAL_STATUS = OK </span></h1>
</h1>
<p>
Blah blah...
</p>

</html>
EOF
```

At least this particular version of `mail` sets the content type to `text/plain` by default, unless overridden. See the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bsd-mailx/bsd-mailx.1.en.html) for notes on `-a` and the MIME headers.

Note that *other versions of the `mail` tool may be different*, they may have a different way for setting headers. I also didn't check the HTML syntax at all: you may want to actually check the proper DOCTYPEs to use, etc. You might also need to check the encoding (`Content-Transfer-Encoding` header), if you do use non-ASCII characters in the message.

Also, to do it properly, you should probably generate a multipart MIME message with both `text/plain` and `text/html` variants. I'm not going to go there either.

As for that code, if you're only looking for the string `KO` from the input file, and passing the file through in full, you could just use `grep` instead of the shell loop. Maybe  something in this direction (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh

emailaddr=whoever@example.org
status=XXX
color=xxx
subject=test
inputfile=foo.txt
msgfile=$(mktemp)
if grep -qe KO "$inputfile"; then
    status='GLOBAL_STATUS = KO'
    color=red
else
    status='GLOBAL_STATUS = OK'
    color=green
fi

> "$msgfile"
cat <<EOF >> "$msgfile" 
<html>
<h1><span style='color:$color;'> $status </span></h1>
</h1>
<pre>
EOF
cat "$inputfile" >> "$msgfile"
cat <<EOF >> "$msgfile" 
</pre>
</html>
EOF

mail -s "$subject" -a 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"' \
    "$emailaddr" < "$msgfile"

rm -f "$msgfile"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I implemented your code, but still, I have no colours for the statuses. I also tried to put the colors with ' or ", same thing. Tried all caps, first letter big.  Changed the email part as I had errors.  `ARG_EMAIL_TO="lola@domain.com"
ARG_EMAIL_FROM="<root@.123>"
ARG_EMAIL_SUBJECT="Check BACK"
(
  echo "To: ${ARG_EMAIL_TO}"
  echo "From: ${ARG_EMAIL_FROM}"
  echo "Subject: ${ARG_EMAIL_SUBJECT}"
  echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'"
  echo
  cat "$msgfile"
) | sendmail -t`

Comment: @Lola, seems to work for me with that `sendmail` command too (and the message text from above). But I didn't test with other clients etc. I don't think I have any other ideas, sorry :/

Comment: @ikkach I made it work. I saw a very strange thing, my last 15 minutes modification were ok. The fact is that from some strange thing all mails went to junk. I deleted my unlucky mails, and I don't know why, I went to deleted, and saw my mails had the green status. Went again trying to find what did I do that was good. Found it. Thank you so very much. :* >:D<

Answer (score 0):

So my last step in this script is to compare the dates from the servers and compare them with today's date. If the date for one server is not today's date DATE = KO.

Tried this:

```
LOG="/home/check_back.log"
date="date +%d-%m-%y -r"
datemail=$(date "+%d-%m-%y")
>LOG

For each server the date is read and printed in the email with: 
echo " " && $date /tmp/check_back.log"  >>$LOG

if [[ $date -lt $datemail ]]; then
    check_date='DATE = KO'
    color='red'
fi
```

I receive the error: [[date +%d-%m-%y -r: command not found.
I think my code doesn't read each servers date, but I have no idea what to do. Can someone help, please?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Thanks all. I fixed it. I need to use < operator, not -lt.